# lex file not compiling due to simple error

Tags: c, unix, gcc, yacc, lex

so i'm trying to compile this .l file using lex utility but it keeps giving me error message:

> lex new_grammar.l
>   "new_grammar.l":line 15: Error: EOF before %}

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, maybe another pair of eyes will see what mistake i'm making. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

"print"         {return print;}
"exit"          {return exit_command;}
[a-zA-Z]        {yylval.id = yytext[0]; return identifier;}
[0-9]+          {yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return number;}
[ \t\n]         ;
[-+=;]          {return yytext[0];}
.               {ECHO; yyerror("unexpected character");}

%%
int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

[image]

Comment: I ran lex on what you pasted and it did not complain.

Comment: did you include any options? like -d or -l

Comment: Nope. Just lex file.l version: flex 2.5.35 Apple(flex-31)

Comment: ahh eureka! I need to run it as flex new_grammar.l

Answer (score 1):

ahh eureka! I need to run it as `flex new_grammar.l` –  mosawi